# How does this recursion solve explosive sum function

Tags: javascript

The question asked how many ways you can make a sum of the number. I have been trying to understand the solving process, but I am so confused about how this recursion worked. What is the value of memo[n] and memo[n][m]. It is an empty array. How is it end up with the correct answer?

```js
var memo = [];

function sum(n, m = n) {
  // console.log("mmeno0",memo)
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (n < 0 || m == 0) return 0;
  if (memo[n] && memo[n][m]) {
    return memo[n][m];
  }
  let total = sum(n, m - 1) + sum(n - m, m);
  if (!memo[n]) {
    memo[n] = [];
  }
  memo[n][m] = total;
  return total;
}

// sum(1) // 1
//sum(2) // 2  -> 1+1 , 2
console.log(sum(3),memo); // 3 -> 1+1+1, 1+2, 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memo standards for memorize and stores the result of previous (partial) result in an array of arrays so they can be reused.  In literature this approach is called dynamic programming.

Comment: can you go more into detail like illustrating your thought process? I understand recursion in factorial function, but when it gets to complex recursion like this I am confused.

Comment: Dynamic programming and recursion are two different concepts.  The idea with dynamic programming is that the final answer consist of sub-results that reoccur.  Let's say you want to count number of parts in a car.  You can count each of the, say 1,800 parts individually, and let's say it takes you 10 seconds to count part so it would take 5 hours.  Another way of doing it is to realize a car consist of components, let's say the door, consist of 100 parts.  You count those parts once and it would take you 1000 seconds.  You remember that.  Other door is the same so 0 time to count.

Comment: Recursion is that idea that a big problem can be broken down into a smaller problems that are solved the same way, and there are eventually a really small problem that has an obvious solution.  An example of this might length of a string, strlen(s).   If the string is empty then the length is obviously 0 (base case), otherwise the length is 1 + strlen(s[1;]) where s[1;] where s[1;] is the string with the first letter removed.  strlen("abc") = 1 + strlen("bc") = 1 + 1 + strlen("c") = 1  + 1 + 1 + strlen("") = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3.